# Passing wrong data for random elements with PHP+MYSQL+JSON+FBGRAPH

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, facebook

## Hello there;

I'm making basic script - save values, then compare it, if it exists - show different class, everything works fine with 99% of entries. I click on button, jquery posts data to mysql, and after that - data has been saved - BUT - there are some of the elements that gets written in with elementid minus one value.

### How my logic works:

```
JSON gets values from Facebook Graph - it got userID like - 19999;
It is now splitted in array; 
Array is getting arranged by names;
And all userids are my button id to pass each userid to mysql;
If user gets clicked it gets written in db;
Then it shows up - if user is there, or not...
```

### Problem

So i click on 99% everyting is working just perfect, can't see no problem; 
But then there are some entries which get written in database with wrong userid.

JSON gives value = 1999 -> same for button id = 1999;
BUT It writes value into database = 1998 [?]
WHY?

All other entries are working just fine, but in all list, there are few expectations.

So i've been googling this problem, can't find any solution or reasoning.

### SQL queries

```
SELECT * FROM checkin WHERE (eid = '".$eid."' AND suid = '".$suid."' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It was in Jquery, i was using

var id,

and variable was called with (+id), now with (id) everything works fine.